# ExtJs sends multiple XHR requests for every item when i hit delete

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have a ExtJs(v3.1) `Ext.grid.GridPanel that loads some records from its store and allows editing.

If i select multiple records, and I click the delete it sends multiple DELETE requests, overwhelms the server, which eventually deletes some of them , returns 404 for the rest.

I don't understand why it sends a second or third request before the first has failed, it just has not returned.

this is the handler for the delete button

```
function onDelete() {
 var recs = userGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
 userGrid.store.remove(recs); //delete multiple selections one at a time
```

}

and the store its based on

```
// Typical Store collecting the Proxy, Reader and Writer together
var store = new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
    proxy: proxy,
    reader: reader,
    writer: writer,
    sortInfo: { // Default sort by day decsending grouped by week
        field: 'day',
        direction: "DSC"
    }, groupField: 'week',


     batch: false, // update each record with an individual XHR request, the server doesnt process batch requests
});
```

this is a screenshot of firebug after i highlighted 5 records and clicked delete

[image: Screenshot of firebug after highlighting 5 records and clicking delete]

Comment: That "batch" flag is probably part of the issue.  Deleting a lot of elements such that you'd wait for responses in between would be pretty slow.

Comment: I added it originally, because it would try to group them into one request with all the ID's when trying to create them. But I just turned it off and it worked perfectly!

Comment: OK - I already had done so but I deleted it because it was really just a guess :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gee that line:

```
 batch: false, // update each record with an individual XHR request, the server doesnt process batch requests
```

sure looks suspicious ... I bet that that's just what Ext does, given that it'd be pretty slow to actually wait for each response before sending the next.

(I agree however that just blasting out a whole bunch of overlapping HTTP transactions like that is not terribly smart.)

Comment: I am afraid of undesired behavior which caused me to add this declaration, but it fixed this. It still sends separate requests, but not multiple ones for each record, exactly what i wanted. :D.

Comment: and yeah I can't imagine a situation where doing that would be desirable.. haha

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue, but I was able to fix it by calling onCommitChanges() on the data store once the store is modified.